# JSON_EXTRACT and square brackets

Tags: mysql, json

I am not able to use  (mysql) `JSON_EXTRACT` on a JSON record like:

```
[{"id": 156, "betas": [{"id": 324, "title": "mario", "gammas": [{"id": 190, "path": "file.png"}]}]}]
```

In particular I fails to get into the innermost square brackets:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(main, '$[0].betas.$[0]') FROM mydb.mytable;
```

returns `NULL`. I tried with a number of variants, but I fails to get the right one.

I note that `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(main, '$[0].betas') ...` returns

```
[{"id": 324, "title": "mario", "gammas": [{"id": 190, "path": "file.png"}]}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` refers to the root of the JSON object, it doesn't make sense to have `$[0]` in the middle of the path.

Try:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(main, '$[0].betas[0]') FROM mydb.mytable
```

This should return

```
{"id": 324, "title": "mario", "gammas": [{"id": 190, "path": "file.png"}]}
```

Comment: your JSON_EXTRACT syntax is incorrect. encapsulate using parens and be sure to close the single quote on the 2nd arg

Comment: wow, don't know how I did that, probably was just typing too fast. I was more concerned with getting the syntax of the path expression right.